# Adding XML Element in specific position JAVA

Tags: java, xml, element

My current code places `schoolBoard` inside `course`, not before or after it as I would like.

```java
        Node Course = doc.getElementsByTagName("course").item(0);
         
        Element schoolBoard = doc.createElement("schoolBoard");
        schoolBoard.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("UCDSB Secondary Virtual Program"));
        Course.appendChild(schoolBoard);
```

How do I create `schoolBoard` *before* `course`?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Course.appendChild() you need to find the parent of Course and insert your schoolBoard there. Now you can define the position where to add using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#insertBefore-org.w3c.dom.Node-org.w3c.dom.Node-

So your code could contain something like

```
Course.getParentNode().insertBefore(schoolBoard, Course);
```